# parse.com: parse deploy not working

Tags: parse-platform, command

I have running project on parse.

Suddenly it stops deploying files on server.

When I run **parse deploy** command then it throws error as 
**Unable to authenticate app. Please make sure your applicationId and masterKey in "config/global.json" is correct**

I have tried to do same with new account from my desktop but same error.

I am using windows 7 and Js Sdk v2.1.0(parse).

Please help to get sort out this issue.

I done with google no resolution found.

Comment: When was it last working? Do you have the most recent version of the tool? What version of the js library is it using?

Comment: It was working on last friday and on satuday it suddenly stop working.
Js version used is latest one. Also windows command line tool of parse is also latest because after this problem I have downloaded latest version and tried with it. But problem still remain. Also I have created another account and try with that but same.

Comment: Suggest you ask on the parse forum